# SCP copy through SSH not working - permission denied and stdin is not a tty

Tags: ssh, scp

I am working on a piece of Python code on my Windows 10 Pro machine, but need a package that is only available on Mac and Linux. I have used SSH to connect to a Linux machine in the lab I work in (interestingly enough, even though Google tells me I shouldn't be able to SSH directly from my Windows terminal instead of something like Putty, I can...?) and am trying to copy over a test .py file, so I can see if I can code on my laptop, copy the files over, and run the files through SSH on the Linux machine. However, when I try to use scp, this appears in the terminal (Including what I typed in so you can see if maybe I'm doing something wrong):

```
$ scp /Desktop/Everything-else/Python/scp-test.py rmanton2@[computer address]:/home/rmanton2/Desktop/Python
rmanton2@[computer address]'s password:
stdin: is not a tty
/Desktop/Everything-else/Python/scp-test.py: Permission denied
```

Why does this happen? My googling has either produced results that don't apply to my situation or that I don't understand (I've never really done much with my computer besides using the Internet, this is the first time I've done anything with the terminal.) If someone could explain exactly what I can do to fix this in a simple way, I'd really appreciate it.

I'm an admin AND the only user account on my laptop, so I don't know why I wouldn't have permission to access it. When googling to find solutions to the tty issue, I couldn't find any that I actually understood well enough to work. (There was one that had a block of code to run, but it had a '...' to indicate something else should be put there, and I had no idea what... My question has been marked as a possible duplicate of that question, but as I said, that didn't help me, and I doubt commenting on a 5 year old post will get me many answers.)

If it's necessary info, the OS on the Linux machine is ScientificLinux 6.9.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I seem to have found an answer. I had to use scp from my own computer rather than first using ssh to get into the other computer, and I had to change directory so the prompt said "C:>" instead of "C:\Users\Reka>". I still get "stdin: is not a tty", but the file appeared in the correct file on the other computer. I swear I tried this before, but I guess I did something different.